# Hovering outside div's radius

Tags: hover, css

I am having a problem with using border-radius in combination with a hover state.
The hover state only should happen when the cursor is on top of the circle. So not when it's in the div's corner.

Example: http://tinker.io/e059c

It's seems to be impossible to do this, so a useful workaround is welcome.

Comment: does it need to be css border radius? perhaps try an SVG

Answer (score 0):

From what you have mentioned,

> The hover state only should happen when the cursor is on top of the
>   circle. So not when it's in the div's corner.

Here is the [WORKING SOLUTION](http://tinker.io/e059c/4).

**The HTML:**

```
<div class='test'></div>
<div class="center"></div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.test{
    height:100px;
     width:100px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;  
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;  
    position:absolute;

}

.test:hover{
    background-color:blue;
}

.center{height:90px;
     width:90px;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;  
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;  
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. Hope this helps.